# Specifying database credentials then setting a connection tenancy for Laravel

Tags: laravel, tenancyforlaravel

I have specified the connection name and password, however when I run the command it does not create a new connection

Illuminate\Database\QueryException

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user

`Tenant::create([ 'tenancy_db_username' => 'foo', 'tenancy_db_password' => 'bar', ]);`

**I just want to create a name and password for each tenant db to monitor and control traffic**

[I Followed the Documentation Examples Here](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/customizing-databases/)

I tried creating a default connection (it will be created by default) and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're encountering issues with database connection configuration. Firstly,

> $tenant = Tenant::create();

can indeed be called without parameters, and it should connect and create a new database. It's advisable to check your `.env` file, especially the `DB_CONNECTION` parameter, to ensure it matches your database setup.

Additionally, please review the `config/tenancy.php` file, particularly the `'database'` section, to ensure it's configured correctly. If everything looks fine there, double-check your database credentials to ensure they are correctly specified.